# SQLCommand and SqlDataReader error

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sqldatareader

Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

This error occurs on this line

```
string ingredientName = reader2.GetString(0);
```

My code:

```
var ingredientList = new List<Ingredient>();

SqlCommand staffCommand = new SqlCommand();

string conString = EventsUnlimited.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseEventsUnlimitedConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT IngredientID, Quantity FROM CourseIngredients WHERE CourseID =" + courseID, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Obtains the columns from customer
                int ingredientID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                decimal quantity = reader.GetDecimal(1);

                string ingredientNameConstruct;

                SqlCommand ingredientCommand = new SqlCommand();
                string conString2 = EventsUnlimited.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseEventsUnlimitedConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(conString2))
                {
                    connection2.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand ("SELECT IngredientName FROM Stock WHERE IngredientID =" + ingredientID, connection2))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            string ingredientName = reader2.GetString(0);
                            ingredientNameConstruct = ingredientName;
                        }  
                    }
                }

                ingredientList.Add(new Ingredient(courseID, ingredientNameConstruct, ingredientID, quantity));
            }
        }
    }

    return ingredientList;
}
```

I am not sure as to what is causing this issue. There is data in the table and the row I am trying to read from.

Comment: This can be done with a single query if you JOIN the two tables.

Comment: Your second `reader` isn't reading, and you also need to parameterize your queries to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: As stated, you should use parameters. This would also be less code and easier to read if you applied a proper join in sql and used a sql command to retrieve all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `Read()` method for your `reader2` object which actually reads a row against the result returned, add that before actually reading column values:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
{
      if(reader2.Read()) // this is needed
      {
          string ingredientName = reader2.GetString(0);
          ingredientNameConstruct = ingredientName;
      }
}
```

if you are expecting multiple rows then use `while` loop, and if it is always a single row to be expecting as result them you can use `reader2.ExecuteScalar` too as **@bradbury9** mentioned in the comment:

```
string ingredientName = command2.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
ingredientNameConstruct = ingredientName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [DataReader.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.read(v=vs.100).aspx) Method in your `reader2` DataReader to get the results.